# I have an interblockage in my code which is about linear process calculation

Tags: c, linux, process, mpi

we suppose that we have a n linear  process P1...P2 , & every process will communicate with his neighbours(left & right) , & we have a vector X of size n , & 
Xi= (X-1 + Xi + Xi+1 )/4  & 0< i < n-1
in this case every  process i send data Xi to his neighbour Xi+1 & Xi-1 and receive Xi-1 & Xi+1 from i-1 & i+1 , for calculate the new value of Xi

this is what i have done but i had an interblockage , so please help to find the errors :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int world_rank;
int world_size; 
double rec=0,rec2=0;
int i,j;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
double x[world_size];

for(i=0;i<world_size;i++)x[i]=i;

for(i=0;i<world_size;i++){
    if(world_rank==i){
        if(world_rank==0){
            int a1=MPI_Send(&x[i],1,MPI_INT,i+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            int a2=MPI_Recv(&rec,1,MPI_INT,i+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            if((a1==MPI_SUCCESS)&&(a2==MPI_SUCCESS)){
                x[i]=(x[i]+rec)/4;  
                printf("x[%d]= %f\n",i,x[i]);
              }
            }else if(world_rank==world_size-1){
                            int a4=MPI_Send(&x[i],1,MPI_INT,i-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            int a3=MPI_Recv(&rec,1,MPI_INT,i-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

                            if((a3==MPI_SUCCESS)&&(a4==MPI_SUCCESS)){
                                x[i]=(x[i]+rec)/4;  
                                printf("x[%d]= %f\n",i,x[i]);
                             }
                        }else{
                            int a7=MPI_Recv(&rec,1,MPI_INT,i+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); 
                            int a8=MPI_Recv(&rec2,1,MPI_INT,i-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); 
                            int a5=MPI_Send(&x[i],1,MPI_INT,i+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                            int a6=MPI_Send(&x[i],1,MPI_INT,i-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

                            if((a5==MPI_SUCCESS)&&(a5==MPI_SUCCESS)&&(a5==MPI_SUCCESS)&&(a5==MPI_SUCCESS)){
                                x[i]=(x[i]+x[i+1]+x[i-1])/4;
                                    printf("x[%d]= %f\n",i,x[i]);
                            }
}                           
}
}

/*for(i=0;i<world_size;i++)
printf("x[%d]= %f\n",i,x[i]);*/

}
```

Comment: Use `MPI_Sendrecv` instead in order to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: how can i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the deadlock, imagine how it would run if two processes are used: both processes would call `MPI_Send()` and none of them would receive the messages because `MPI_Send()` is blocking.

Hence, to overcome this problem, the messages have to be received! There are many solutions available:

1. As suggested by Hristo Iliev, you can use [`MPI_Sendrecv()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Sendrecv.3.php). Indeed, the documentation of OpenMPI cleary refers to your situation as a typical use of `Sendrecv()`:

> `MPI_Sendrecv()` combines in one call the sending of a message to one destination and the receiving of another message, from another process. A send-receive operation is useful for executing a shift operation across a chain of processes. If blocking sends and receives are used for such a shift, then one needs to order the sends and receives correctly (for example, even processes send, then receive; odd processes receive first, then send) in order to prevent cyclic dependencies that may lead to deadlock.

The following [example](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/mpiexmpl/src/exchange/C/exchange/solution.html) illustrates this option.

2. Non-blocking communications can be used through the function [`MPI_Isend()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Isend.3.php) and [`MPI_Irecv()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Irecv.3.php). But there must be a call to a function like [`MPI_Waitall()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Waitall.html) to ensure that all messages were actually sent and received.

   ```
   #include <mpi.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main(int argc,char *argv[])
   {
       int  world_size, world_rank;
       MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
       MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
       MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);

       int x[world_size];

       x[world_rank]=world_rank;

       int up=world_rank+1;
       int down=world_rank-1;
       if(up>=world_size){
           up=MPI_PROC_NULL;
       }
       if(down<0){
           down=MPI_PROC_NULL;
       }
       MPI_Request req[4];
       MPI_Isend(&x[world_rank], 1, MPI_INT, up, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]); 
       MPI_Isend(&x[world_rank], 1, MPI_INT, down, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
       MPI_Irecv(&x[(world_rank-1+world_size)%world_size], 1, MPI_INT, down, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[2]);
       MPI_Irecv(&x[(world_rank+1+world_size)%world_size], 1, MPI_INT, up, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[3]);
       MPI_Waitall(4, req, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

       printf("rank %d has %d %d %d\n",world_rank,x[(world_rank-1+world_size)%world_size],x[world_rank],x[(world_rank+1+world_size)%world_size]); 

       MPI_Finalize();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

To be compiled by `mpicc main.c -o main -Wall` and ran by `mpirun -np 10 main`.

Comment: Sends of a single integer are almost guaranteed to be buffered. The real problem is that the code for the intermediate ranks starts with a pair of blocking receives and those cannot return before both left and right messages have arrived. Also, you do not need to make both the sends and the receives non-blocking, only the logically first set of operations. In you case, that would be `MPI_Isend` followed by `MPI_Recv` followed by `MPI_Waitall`. BTW, `MPI_Sendrecv` in Open MPI is implemented as `MPI_Irecv` / `MPI_Send` / `MPI_Wait`.

Comment: look at my answer and try that code , and tell me why ?

Comment: @HristoIliev : thanks for your enlighted feedback! Indeed, the code did not freeze if two or three processes are used, likely because buffered send mode is used.

Comment: thanx a lot , i know it's late but thanx